# passing data from parent class to child class through props, but props not returning anything in child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React JS.

My parent class App.js, my Child class is SomeClass.js:

In my App.js, I have the following:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authaccount: {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            },
            authenticated: false
        };
    }
      render(){
        return(
            <Router>
        
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/somelink/abc" exact component={SomeClass} authenticated={this.state.authenticated} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    
    }



}


export default App;
```

I have another React component:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item:[
                {
                    name: "",
                    material: "",
                },
            ],
        };
    }


    componentDidMount = () =>{
        if(this.props.authenticated === true && this.props.authaccount.email === "someemail@email.com") {
            this.someMethod();
        }else if(this.props.authenticated === true) {
            console.log(this.props.authaccount.email);   //getting undefined
            this.anotherMethod();
        }

    }

}
export default SomeClass;
```

App.js is the parent class.
In my SomeClass component, I want to access the authenticated property and the email property of the "authaccount" which is present in the state of App.js

My Question is how to pass the authenticated value and email value from App.js to SomeClass.js ?

I tried to console.log(this.props.authaccount.email);   //but still getting undefined

Comment: Hom do you use `SomeClass `?

Comment: "I tried to console.log(this.props.authaccount.email); //but did not get any data" Did you pass the properties to SomeClass component in App component
<SomeClass authenticated={authenticated} authaccount={authaccount}></SomeClass> like this ?

Comment: I would highly recommend using [**useHistory()**](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) hook from "react-router-dom" for sending props to different routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the prop like this:

```
 <Route path="/somelink/abc" exact component={() => (<SomeClass authenticated={this.state.authenticated} authaccount={this.state.authaccount} />)}  />
```